# Taking content from two different excel sources at the same time with Oledb

Tags: c#, oledb

My problem is that,

There are two excel files. And i should take the first one's content than do a search operation depending on the first search. I mean,

Assume excel1 has this content,

***Column1***
mike
john
elvis

and excel 2 has that,

***Column1*** ***Column2***
mike     1999
elvis    2000
jeremy   1988
john     1957
eric     1944

I want to take the birthdays of names which appears in excel1. So, the result of this search is,

***Column1*** ***Column2***
mike 1999
elvis 2000
john 1957

Now, the question is coming, how can i take two excel files' content at the same time with oledb? I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Did you even try it? Show us your code to open the first document, and where it fails to open the 2nd one!

Comment: No i did not, because i do not know how to call two excel files in one query. That's why i ask for your help.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward with SQL Server Integration Services, You should try it.

Comment: @jasonoco: you suggest to crack a nut with a sledgehammer?

Answer (score 0):

When using OLEDB to access two documents, you will have to create two different connections. This means, you cannot use a single SQL join to get the data from both documents into a combined table. What you can do:

- read the content of doc 1 into some data structure (for example, a `List<string>`)
- read the content of doc 2 into another data structure (for example, a `Dictionary<string,string>`)
- loop over all elements of the list and assign each of them the values from the dictionary.

As an alternative, you could use COM interop to copy both sheets into a third excel document and do the SQL query there, but that solution needs Excel to be installed on the production machine, and IMHO it seems not to be worth the effort for the requirements you described.